# React Native Android Slider cannot slide vertically on device

Tags: android, react-native, slider

I've used the `Slider` component on `React Native` `0.43` using the following code. It works fine for iOS as it has a nice big "button" for user to hold and drag. But on android it is just a small dot and I find that I could not drag it vertically (1/10 tries are successful). I find that the "drag" get captured by the `ScrollView` in the background instead. Help?

```
      <Slider
        minimumValue={minValue}
        maximumValue={maxValue}
        step={step}
        style={styles.slider}
        value={parseInt(input.value)}
        onSlidingComplete={onSlidingComplete}
        onValueChange={onValueChange}
      />

  slider: {
    marginRight:-100,
    marginLeft:-100,
    width:250,
    transform: [
      { rotateZ : '-90deg' },
    ],
  },
```

[image: vertical slider]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, you need to override the `PanResponder` for the `Slider`. For some reason, Android just does not cope well when it is rotated vertically.

```
componentWillMount () {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      // Ask to be the responder:
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true
    })
}
```

Then simply apply the `PanHandler` to the `Slider`:

```
<Slider
    {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
    ... />
```

This gives it absolute priority over that pesky `ScrollView`.

Also it would be best practice to stop the `ScrollView` from vertically panning at all when the `Slider` is in use, which sometimes happens when you drag both components in quick succession.

```
<ScrollView scrollEnabled={!this.state.sliding}>

    <Slider
        onValueChange={() => {
          this.setState({
            sliding: true
          })
        }}
        onSlidingComplete={() => {
          this.setState({
            sliding: false
          })
        }}
      ... />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with `react-native`'s slider component behaving weird on real iOS devices so I opted to use [react-native-slider](https://github.com/jeanregisser/react-native-slider) instead.